# Python Selenium Google Login Bot fails on Linux

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I wrote a bot that login google with python selenium. It works on my local windows pc. But when i try this code on my jenkins linux it fails. I tried tons of way to log in. Here is just a sample to one of my tried ways.

```
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys("my_email")
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("my_password")
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
```

this code works for my windows pc. But when i run code on Jenkins it raises below exceptions

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input class="whsOnd zHQkBf" name="password" type="password"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timeout loading page after 15000ms
```

that mentioned class is here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPXa6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!
Use [Seleniumwire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) with [undetected browser v2](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#bot-detection)

> Note: put chromedriver in your sys path.

```
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
import time

options = {}
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=hash')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://gmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('your-email')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('you-password')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button').click()
```

In addition to this, selenium wire has many awesome features, check out Github [repository](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)